# Recording CPU time for GA algorithm in Matlab using optimization toolbox

Tags: matlab, time, genetic-algorithm

I am using global optimization toolbox to run genetic algorithm on Matlab. However, I do not see any documentation or function to record the CPU time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `cputime` explained [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cputime.html). It returns time in seconds. Although, `tic` and `toc` are a better choice for measuring performance in Matlab codes.

A sample code :

```matlab
startTime = cputime;
% GA Code
endTime = cputime;
cpu_time_consumed = endTime - startTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this can also be done using the "Run and Time" option available in Matlab.